# convert Reference to shared pointer

Tags: c++, object-slicing

I have a function like

```
void Element::setNodes(const BaseClass& input0, const BaseClass& input1)
```

This is called by passing a derived class.

```
setInputNodes(DerivedClass1, DerivedClass2)
```

The trouble I have is that I want to store the nodes in a vector.  I have this

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BaseClass>> m_inputNode;
```

and the function as

```
void Element::setNodes(const BaseClass& input0, const BaseClass& input1)
{
m_inputNode.push_back(input0);
m_inputNode.push_back(input1);
}
```

This doesn't work and I have to store it as a pointer otherwise I experience object slicing.  Will I need to change the API and pass pointers?  I want to change as little as possible.

Comment: Do you want to create copies of your object or store a reference/pointer to the original objects?

Comment: I want a pointer/reference to the original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you stated,

> I want a pointer/reference to the original.

The only choice is to drop the `shared_ptr` and use a non-owning pointer:

```
std::vector<BaseClass const*> m_inputNode;

void Element::setNodes(BaseClass const& input0, BaseClass const& input1) {
    m_inputNode.push_back(&input0);
    m_inputNode.push_back(&input1);
}
```

(Drop all the `const`s if you need a non-`const` pointer.)

`shared_ptr` fundamentally expresses *ownership*, which doesn’t seem to be what you’re after.

But if I misunderstood you and you actually want to confer (shared) ownership of the objects to your vector, you need to pass the objects into your function via shared pointers as well:

```
void Element::setNodes(std::shared_ptr<BaseClass> input0, std::shared_ptr<BaseClass> input1) {
    m_inputNode.push_back(input0);
    m_inputNode.push_back(input1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you *know* that someone else is managing the lifetime of the vector elements, then use `std::vector<const BaseClass*>` as the type, and use `&input0` etc. when pushing elements to the vector.

It's difficult to use a `std::shared_ptr` pointer here since, at the point of use, you don't know how the object has been created.

If you want to retain your references then you can always enclose them in a `std::reference_wrapper`; set `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<const BaseClass>>` as the type. But the ownership issues are still prevalent; you could end up with a vector of dangling references.

Comment: This was my original idea but I didn't want to worry about ownership issues.

Answer (score 1):

You have to take the pointers to your Elements:

```
void Element::setNodes(const BaseClass& input0, const BaseClass& input1)
{
    m_inputNode.push_back(&input0);
    m_inputNode.push_back(&input1);
}
```

Therefore the `shared_ptr<>`s must point to `const BaseClass`. When you don't want that, you'll have to drop `const` from the parameter specifications.

I don't recommend an API like that for your needs. You don't make explicit for the caller, that you remember pointers to the objects. He might pass in stack allocated or even temporary objects, that are not valid any more, when you later try to use them:

```
myElement.setNodes(createElement0(), createElement1());
```

Prefer to be explicit about what the user of your function has to expect.

```
void Element::setNodes(std::shared_ptr<BaseClass> input0,
                       std::shared_ptr<BaseClass> input1)
{
    m_inputNode.push_back(input0);
    m_inputNode.push_back(input1);
}
```

Now the user has to explicitly provide pointers:

```
myElement.setNodes(std::make_shared<Element>(createElement0()),
                   std::make_shared<Element>(createElement1()));
```

This tells the user, that you are going to take shared ownership of that object.

Comment: @KonradRudolph 1. I don't see, where i did that except for the part, where I explain why the API might be misleading for its user. 2. You are correct here. I'll edit my comment to use `std::make_shared()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for correcting this. Regarding (1), you’re right, your answer explicitly described the caveats. I don’t know why I didn’t see that.